# Where to put spring java-configuration files in maven folder structure

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am new to Springs @Configuration and @Conditional annotation stuff.
I am questioning myself where to put those configuration java files within my maven folder structure.

Up to now I put all my configuration xml files into src/main|test/resources/
But with this new approach there are no xml files any more.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put them in their own package and give it a meaningful name; I usually put them in a special package called `config`. For example, in my projects I have a package called `net.vivin.someproject.config`, and I add the configuration classes in there. This seems like a reasonable approach.